# Show that $\{(1-a,1+a), (1+a,1-a)\}$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In order to show that

$$\{(1-a,1+a), (1+a,1-a)\}$$
is L.I. I did:

$\beta_1(1-a,1+a)+\beta_2(1+a,1-a) = (0,0)\implies\\\begin{cases}\beta_1-\beta_1a + \beta_2 + \beta_2a = 0\\\beta_1+\beta_1a+\beta_2-\beta_2a = 0\end{cases}$

When I sum the two equations I get:

$$2\beta_1 + 2\beta_2 = 0 \implies \beta_1 = -\beta_2$$

But this shows that there is a linear combination different than the trivial, but the exercise asks me to prove that there isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried *subtracting* one equation from the other using $\beta_1=-\beta_2$? By the way it must be assumed in your question that $a\neq0$ otherwise they are linearly dependent.

Comment: It is true that the solution of your system will satisfy $\beta_{1} = -\beta_{2}$. But is any such pair a solution of the system?

Comment: I forgot that the only number that satisfizer $\beta_1 = -\beta_2$ is $\beta_1,\beta_2 = 0$

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions to $\beta_1 = -\beta_2$.  Try subtracting the second equation from the first to see $\beta_1 = \beta_2$.  NOW you can conclude $\beta_1 = \beta_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are only two vectors, we can show that one vector is not a scalar multiple of the other:

If $(1-a,1+a)=c(1+a,1-a)$, then $1-a=c+ca$ and $1+a=c-ca$,

so adding these equations gives $2=2c$ and therefore $c=1$.

Since this gives $1-a=1+a$, there is no solution if $a\ne0$;

so the vectors are linearly independent if $a\ne0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the determinant test to find when these two vectors are linearly independent. Set up your vectors as columns and then take the determinant of that matrix. The vectors are linearly independent iff the determinant is non-zero.

$$det \begin{bmatrix} 1 - a & 1 + a \\  1 + a & 1 - a\end{bmatrix} = (1-a)^{2} - (1+a)^{2} = -4a$$

And so the determinant is non-zero iff $a \neq 0$.